# DrawerLayout with partially visible button

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, drawerlayout

Sorry I couldn't figure out a better title.

I have an `XML` with a `DrawerLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Frame layout for fragment -->
    <FrameLayout
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/Fragment_Container" />

<!-- Need a button visible here that moves left and right with the drawer -->

<!-- This is a right side drawer-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'd like to have a button that's visible at all times on the screen, that when clicked opens/closes the `DrawerLayout`, so it should move in sync with the drawer.
 I've tried putting it inside the drawer and offsetting it to the left, but it just stays a part of it's content.

The only other options I'm considering now is making it detect drawer movement and make it manually slide accordingly.

Bonus issue: It should be shown `on top` of the fragment i.e it should have higher `z-index` than the fragment loaded.

Thanks

Comment: I would either manually slide it or you could look into using CoordinatorLayout. https://github.com/JakeWharton/DrawerBehavior

Comment: @JamesMcCracken  I was certainly hoping I would avoid the manual labor. Thanks for bringing the CoordinatorLayout to my attention.